# Spring Boot/JPA - How i can delete a record from database with DeleteMapping?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, thymeleaf

my problem is that I want to delete a record from the database by id by selecting a button, but when I click the button to delete the corresponding record with the parameter id I get this error:

```
>     HTTP Status 405 – Method Not Allowed
>     Type Status Report
>     
>     Message Method 'GET' is not supported.
>     
>     Description The method received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not supported by the target resource.
```

This is my code:

Thymeleaf:

```
<td>
   <a th:href="@{/delete/{idUser}(idUser=${user.idUser})}">Delete user</a>
</td>
```

Controller:

```
@DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
public String deleteMailbox(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    repo.deleteById(id);
    return "redirect:/userList?success";
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong in my code, or if I forget a specific command or parameter, I would appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: Using `@Transactional` annotation may fix the issue, [read this article](https://www.baeldung.com/transaction-configuration-with-jpa-and-spring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is really self-descriptive. It says that ***Message Method 'GET' is not supported.*** This indicates that you are potentially trying to execute a GET request, but the `GET` endpoint is not registered... And indeed, that is the case, because of this line:

```
<a th:href="@{/delete/{idUser}(idUser=${user.idUser})}">Delete user</a>
```

This will execute the GET request and fail with `405`. The solution would be simple, try executing the `DELETE` request instead of `GET` and it should work then.

The other (not optimal) solution would be to change `@DeleteMapping` to `@GetMapping`, which should also work (but goes against REST principles!!).

Answer (score 1):

```
@DeleteMapping("{id}")
public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> deleteEmployee(@PathVariable long id){
    Employee employee = employeeRepository.findById(id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Not exist id: "+id));
    employeeRepository.delete(employee);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}
```

you can use example from this code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Spring WebMVC/WebFlux has built-in `HiddenHttpMethodFilter` to map a HTTP `POST` method in the pages(eg. JSPs, Freemarker, Thymeleaf, etc) to other HTTP methods(eps. `PUT` and `DELETE`) in the controller. It makes the traditional controller path and naming look like RESTful style.

*All the following steps are based traditional Spring WebMvc.*

1. Wrap the deletion link into a form, put a hidden `_method` field in the form, and set value to `DELETE`. The following is a JSP page fragment.

   ```xml
   <p>
        <c:url var="deleteUrl" value="/users/${user.id}" />
        <form action="${deleteUrl}" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE"></input>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"><jsp:text /></span>
                DELETE
            </button>
        </form>
    </p>
   ```
2. Enable Spring built-in `HiddenHttpMethodFilter` to handle the hidden method. NOTE: Spring Boot users just need to add `spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true` to your *application.properties* to enable it.

   ```java
    @Order(0)
    public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {


        @Override
        protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
            HiddenHttpMethodFilter httpMethodFilter = new HiddenHttpMethodFilter();
            //....

            return new Filter[] { httpMethodFilter, ... };
        }

    }
   ```
3. Then your controller `@DeleteMapping` will handle the deletion post in the page.